# How to change style of Parent div if the radio input is checked in Reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to change the background color of faculty item (.faculty) to red if the respective radio input is checked and ius should be done in using onChange method in Reactjs. I am beginner in reactjs. Thanks in Advance.

```
<div className="faculties">
 <div className='faculty '>
  <label htmlFor="faculty1">Science
   <input type="radio" id='faculty1' name="chooseFaculty" />
  </label>
</div>
<div className='faculty '>
  <label htmlFor="faculty2">Management
   <input type="radio" id='faculty2' name="chooseFaculty" />
  </label>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should use controlled components (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and add some css class to the parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cloud-1sjup?file=/src/App.js)?